# How can I restore GTA V PS3 online to working condition, before it was modded?

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-online

I was playing GTA V on PS3 online, and suddenly modders did a huge money drop. Literally on my head & then raced off the map a few minutes later. I was kicked from the session. Ever since then, the online struggle started. I've tried everything short of deleting my PSN account.

I've scoured Google, Reddit - you name it. Even my new system didn't make a difference. It's just my GTA V account.

Every time I try to play online, it barely starts to load & freezes. I still have the money from the modders. I don't care about the cash, I just wanna be able to play online. How can I delete just GTA V & not my whole PSN.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a few years ago. Modders gave me tons of RP, and put me at the max rank. They didnt give me any unlocks, though, so anything I had not yet unlocked was unobtainable because i could not rank up any longer. I ended up having to contact Rockstar, and they fixed my account for me. They restored my rank to where it was before the modders changed it, after reviewing the session logs.
If all you care about is playing and you're ok with losing some if not all of the money you were given, that would be the route to go, although Rockstar might not respond to your message, since they have stopped supporting the old versions of the game. Also, depending on how long ago the modding occurred, they may not be able to access the logs from that session in order to restore your account.